# How to load images faster and improve performance of website (React JS, GSAP and Netlify)?

Tags: reactjs, image, three.js, gsap

I have a website which is deployed on Netlify below:
https://hungry-mclean-362570.netlify.com/

Github: 
https://github.com/shindosu/mutsuki-portfolio-client

To give a bit of a background, the app is powered with React JS. In the Home page within the `<div id="right-side">`, I have two React components being rendered. They each are powered by THREE JS, and it is alternating between two pictures infinitely with image transition animations via GSAP. So in total, I have 4 images being rendered on the right hand side. The size of the images are around 13MB total (more images to come)

I also have a slider, where if the value hits `>=50` then the styling and the images will change to let the user know the "category" of the images that they are looking at.

Now, it is no where near being done so don't mind the incompleteness. What's bothering me is the loading time of the images (handled by THREE JS, GSAP) is taking an insanely long time to load, which I think is also affecting the loading time of the other elements as well.

How am I able to speed up the loading process? 
I tried decreasing the image sizes (it was 60MB before..currently 13MB!); am trying to shred off more but the most I can get down to is around 600~KB/img without losing any substantial quality.

Are there any other way to get around this? This will be a portfolio website so there's more images that will be in the projects page, so I'm assuming if I continue the way that I'm doing right now the outcome is going to be as or more worse than the page that I am working on.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Those huge PNG images you have should be JPEGs instead. Even as PNGs, running them through OxiPNG gives me about 33% savings on their size.

Comment: Apart from finding a way to reduce the image sizes (I think they're probably still too large), some techniques you could look into would be: 1) A preloader before entering the site? At least all main assets would be loaded by the time you enter the site. 2) Only load the slider images you see first, defer the others. 3) Maybe use placeholder assets during load? 4) You could optimise the images further, use webp format for example?

Comment: Shot you a PR that uses JPEGs instead of PNGs for the photos: https://github.com/shindosu/mutsuki-portfolio-client/pull/9

Comment: You also have full copies of three.js and gsap.js there; if there are smaller builds with only the features you require, that'd be better.

Comment: You're also using images that are 1200 x 1800 but are displaying much smaller than that. The console is giving you a warning `THREE.WebGLRenderer: Texture has been resized from (1198x1800) to (1024x1024).` so you might consider using images that are power-of-two to avoid wasting bandwidth.

Comment: Thanks guys! Converted to PNG to JPG and also cleaned up some of my files. Now it loads way faster! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

To load images faster in a React application you can use one of the following techniques:

1. Use lazy loading method --> The image loads only when the user scrolls to it.
2. Use blur technique --> This loads the images in low resolution initially before the original load
3. Use JPEG-XR and WebP instead of PNG, JPG etc.

For more details you can refer to https://teacode.io/blog/how-to-speed-up-your-react-app-using-cloudinary-and-lazy-loading

Note: I am not an expert. I was also searching how to increase load speed of images and came across some articles like that mentioned above.